# How to call onclick jquery function having dynamic data, Asp.net Mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am loading packages using for-each loop, clearly from code.....

```
<div class="row">             
  @foreach(var items in ViewBag.packages)
  {  
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="price-table-area">
        <div class="fixed-img sec-bg5"></div>
        <ul class="proce-table">
          <li class="price-prdct"><i>$</i>@items.NewPrice<i>/m</i></li>
          <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SignUp" onclick="packageSelect(@ViewBag.PackageId)">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

I am calling function `packageSelect` on click which invokes ajax call to controller action. As can be seen that I am passing `@viewbag.PackageId` parameter to function.

Controller action

```
public ActionResult SelectPackage(int PackageId)
{
    Session["Package"] = PackageId;
    return this.Json(string.Empty); ;
}
```

Script

```
<script>
  function packageSelect(PackageId) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("SelectPackage", "Home")',
      dataType: "JSon",
      data: { "PackageId": PackageId },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // $("#SecondInfo").focus({ scrollTop: "0px" });
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact-us').offset().top }, 'slow');
      },
      error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
  };
</script>
```

Is it right way to call like that? The problem is function not called.

Comment: Don't you need an @ in front of the foreach? Is that a typo in your post?

Comment: @BJ Safdie thanks for reply, no everything works fine, i have removed some code, it got too complex with nested foreachs....i am looking for only proper way to call jquery function....

Comment: Seems ur page get posted before ur ajax call 
use " return" statement in ur function false

Comment: Far better these days to use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and avoid polluting your mark-up with behavior. Add the `PackageId` as a `data-` attribute and use `$('.yourClassName').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('packageId'); ...});`

Comment: does your console throw any error?

Comment: thanks for reply, i am looking for an alternative way also but through ajax is my priority...as i am working on single page applcation and i have set some session variables for that....so cant think other way

Comment: yes it is 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan, Was your last comment in response to mine? (not sure what your referring to). And as others have noted, you need to change the input to a button with `type="button"`, or include `return false;` in the script or both the ajax call and the normal submit will occur

Comment: i usually upvote your valued comments @StephenMuecke ....my reply was over all supportive people thanks

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan, You noted your getting a 500 error. That's usually the result of an exception being thrown on the server (or specifying the wrong `dataType`). You can use you browser tools (Network Tab) to inspect the details)

Comment: yes thats the case i think i have updated question with controller's action

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan, If your using jquery v1.9+ then `return Json(string.Empty)` may throw that exception. Test this by using (say) `return Json("success");`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you were right, problem was in parameters, after checking XSR data, i come to know that..... thanks for the effort.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all the seriousness, I don't think this is a good way to do this.

Instead you should approach to it more clearer-

Use `data` attributes.

`<button class="submit" data-id="@items.PackageId">SignUp</button>`

**And then-**

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id'); //attribute's value
    packageSelect(id); //passing the value to function
});
```

**P.S.-** 
Also I suppose you are iterating the id, If yes then you shouldn't have used it as -

`@ViewBag.PackageId`

It should be (if its iterating and not going to stay the same)-
`@items.PackageId`

Comment: Nice!  I was thinking of this as an alternative, but I was on my iPad and editing code really sux on an iPad.  Also, I did not know that jQuery automagically pulls data- attributes into the data() collection.  I always used .attr() to get them. Thanks for updating me!

Comment: @Manoz i really lost my mind on that mistake,,,,, thanks for answering and sory for late accept due to internet problem,,,cheers

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan, np, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your input is of `submit` type change its type to `button`. So when you click the button `form` will be `posted` and `onclick` will not`fire`.

```
<input type="button" class="submit" value="SignUp"
                            onclick="packageSelect(@ViewBag.PackageId)">
```

Comment: thanks for answer, @Ahmed i don't think thats the case, i have used multiple ajax calls befor on that page....

Comment: Yes but `submit` button will post the form try to change its type and than check.

Comment: i have changed submit type to button but nothing worked

Comment: Check your browser console to see what is the error ?

Comment: firstly it was server error 500, not its unexpected token ) error when i applied Stephen and BJ 's helpfull mentions

Comment: I don't think BJ's code will execute because in that code `function` is not being `called` instead a `new function` is being created so just try what i have said. And `500` error means there is error in your `controller method`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think click accepts parameters that way.  Try

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="SignUp"
      onclick="function(){packageSelect(@ViewBag.PackageId);}">
```

I also agree with Mairaj that the type='submit' is suspicious.

Comment: Please post a sample of the HTML from the browser source code so we can see the generated code.

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking sir

Comment: In chrome, go to the Developer Tools and then in the page right click the input button and choose Inspect from the menu.  In the dev tools window, it will show the HTML.  Copy it and show us what the browser actually receives.

Comment: Also are you sure you dId not accidentally type in a parenthesis instead of a curly brace?

Comment: in firebug console i am getting "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
function(){packageSelect();} "

Comment: `onclick="function(){packageSelect(@ViewBag.PackageId);}` this won't work because you are `not calling` the function instead you are `defining` a function.

Comment: @mairaj, yes. Events expect handler functions. It is correct to pass in a function reference, and this code passes the handler as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pass PackageId value from ViewBag to the function packageSelect? If you are just passing the value to contoller action using ajax call, then I think it can be directly accessed in the action method from ViewBag.

And if you are making ajax call to another controller action then, There is TempData collection you can use to store PackageId.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am working on single page application and already have called the action 3,4 times..... thats not the case you thinking

Comment: my question was about the parameter you pass in ajax call, why do you need to pass that?